# Change the style (title bar color, border) of winforms, that is , of the non-client area

Tags: c#, .net, area, nonclient

Is there any simple way to change the color of the title bar of winforms , change the look and feel of the non-client area ?

i have found this link, but it seems to be very typical for a beginner :

[Drawing Custom Borders in Windows Forms](http://geekswithblogs.net/kobush/articles/CustomBorderForms.aspx)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896294/how-to-change-the-window-style-of-a-form-outside-your-app

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing all stuff your self you can use free library like Krypton

https://github.com/ComponentFactory/Krypton